# How to sort autocomplete results by post date?

Tags: nodes, ajax

I have a content type named "News" which contains a node reference field named "Related News" in autocomplete mode.
Does anyone knows how to sort the results when i write something? I need to get the most recent nodes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use views entity reference widget.you can custom you result like want you want.

[this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2305545) is good tutorial for you achieve your job.I hope learn it and use  it in future project and issues.